# what is the usage of the template parameter of the std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator?

Tags: c++, stl, polymorphism, allocator

I'm currently learning the polymorphic allocator, I watched some videos and trying to understand it. If I have this code:

```cpp
class MyClass {
public:
    MyClass(int val = 0) : m_val(val) {
        std::cout << "MyClass constructed with value: " << val << std::endl;
    }
    ~MyClass() {
        std::cout << "MyClass destroyed with value: " << m_val << std::endl;
    }
private:
    int m_val;
};
int main() {
    char buffer[1024];
    std::size_t buffer_size = sizeof(buffer);
    // Use a monotonic buffer resource
    {
        std::pmr::monotonic_buffer_resource buffer_resource{buffer, buffer_size, std::pmr::null_memory_resource()};
        std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<byte> allocator{ &buffer_resource };
        //std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<MyClass> allocator{ &buffer_resource }; //still OK to use
        {
            std::pmr::vector<MyClass> vec(allocator);
            vec.reserve(256);
            for(int i = 0; i < 256; i++){
                vec.emplace_back(i);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

What is the difference between `std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<byte>` and `std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<MyClass>`? Why both can work fine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

> Allocator - An allocator that is used to acquire/release memory and to construct/destroy the elements in that memory. The type must meet the requirements of Allocator. The behavior is undefined (until C++20) / The program is ill-formed (since C++20) if `Allocator::value_type` is not the same as `T`.

So, if `Allocator::value_type` is not the same as `MyClass`:

- The behavior is undefined (until C++20)
- The program is ill-formed (since C++20)

The correct way to use it is therefore to use `std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<MyClass>`.

> Why both can work fine?

The `std::pmr::vector<MyClass>` constructor ...

```cpp
constexpr explicit vector(
    const std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<MyClass>& alloc) noexcept;
```

... converts the allocator you supply into a `std::pmr::polymorphic_allocator<MyClass>` which uses the same memory resource as your `allocator`.

Comment: Thank you! So I should keep the allocator has the same type with the element type?

Comment: @Kevineyeson Exactly!

Comment: One more question is:
I find this constructor in the class `polymorphic_allocator`: `template< class U >
polymorphic_allocator( const polymorphic_allocator<U>& other ) noexcept;`
So basically, the allocator type will be converted to correct type. Will that lead to some UB?

Comment: @Kevineyeson The converting contructor can be used to create an allocator for a different `T` that uses the same memory resource as `other`. No UB in doing that.

Comment: So is that mean, I can always use `std::byte` as the type of the `polymorphic_allocator`? Because I watched some lectures (CppCon2017 and 2019) and they said `polymorphic_allocator<byte> is the one true allocator vocabulary type`.

Comment: @Kevineyeson You can and you can't. If you create a `byte` allocator , you must then  convert it into the proper allocator type, like in the `vector` case.  It will not use your allocator but create a proper one using the same memory resource.